# How to make printable bar graph with HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css, printing, graph

I recently created a web page that uses HTML5 and CSS3 to draw a bar graph.  This is my first time doing this, and I followed the instructions given here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/bar-graph-with-css3-and-progressive-enhancement.html#fbid=gG6mmpDnQDn

The long and the short of it is to create a DIV tag for each bar and use CSS to set the size and color of each bar.  Specifically, use the background-color CSS attribute.

This works great until the user prints the page, and I do expect the page to be printed many times.

The problem is that web browsers typically omit background images and colors from the printed version of the page.  This results in the bars not printing at all!

Chrome allows the user to check a box indicating that background images and colors should print, but it isn't practical for me to say, "To print this, use Chrome and be sure to check that box yada yada yada."

One stop-gap measure I've deployed is to use CSS to specify that when the document is printed, a border should be drawn around the bars, but this is just a border; it doesn't fill the bar at all.

How can I make a bar graph with HTML5 and CSS3 that will print correctly under most browser configurations.

Comment: You can draw the graph using SVG.  There are plenty of tools that do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add [**this style**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) for Chrome:

```
:root {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}
```

That reduces your user instructions to simply, "To print this, use Chrome."

Otherwise, you may need to resort to SVG like @MiltoxBeyond suggested.